# getRange Not Referencing Correctly

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41561772/change-cell-value-based-on-cell-color-in-google-spreadsheet) by [Shyam Kansagra](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5912837/shyam-kansagra), I have modified the following code to check a Google Sheets cell background color and change a different cell's value based on that color.

I am close, but currently `getRange` is only checking column 6. I want it to check columns 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, and if any cell in that row is red, write "Red" in column 11. When getting the BG color, I thought `bg = sheet1.getRange(i+2, 6, 10, 5).getBackground();` would check all 5 columns, but currently it is only checking column 6.

Here is the full code:

```
function myFunction() {
  var sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Compliance Main");

  var data1 = sheet1.getDataRange().getValues();  //2D array of sheet1 cell values
  var bg;

  for(var i=0; i<data1.length; i++)
  {
    bg = sheet1.getRange(i+2, 6, 6, 5).getBackground();
    if(bg == "#ff0000")  //Add more colors in else if and else if
    {
      sheet1.getRange(i+2, 11).setValue("Red");  //Set value in corresponding row
    } else if(bg == "#ffff00")
    {
      sheet1.getRange(i+2, 11).setValue("Yellow");
    } else if(bg == "#ffffff")
    {
      sheet1.getRange(i+2, 11).setValue("White");
    }
  }
}
```

For more clarity, Here is a screenshot: [image] of the erroneous sheet - as you can see, I want it to reference the whole group of columns, but it is only referencing column 6.

I apologize if these edits are rough, I am a beginner with js. Thank you for any help you may provide!

Comment: Thank you @I'-'I. I've tried `bg = sheet1.getRange(i+2, 6, 6, 5).getBackgrounds();` and now it does not return any results. I'm looking over the docu and am having issues relating it to how I've set this up.

Comment: This only returns a value for the upper leftmost cell in a range.     bg = sheet1.getRange(i+2, 6, 6, 5).getBackground(); You must use getBackgrounds() instead.
  It returns a  2d array of background colors for each cell in a range (much like 'getValues()' returns an array of values).

Comment: So in your line 2, column K, what is the desired output?  Red, White, Yellow, Red, White? Also see http://googlescriptreference.com/category/spreadsheet-range-getbackgrounds/